# openCV 2.4.10 lost cinepak radius codec

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I am working on a Windows 7 64 bit platform.

**Before:**
I was using OpenCV 2.4.6, compiled by myself with CodeBlocks and a MinGW compiler. When recording a video, I was able to select the Cinepak Radius Codec (CVID) and all my world was shinny. I don't remember tweaking a lot the configuration of CMAKE when creating the CodeBlocks project to compile OpenCV.

**Now:**
I download the last stable version OpenCV 2.4.10 and I have to use this one. So I applied the same recipe: CMAKE, CodeBlocks project, compile. But then I cannot choose the Cinepak Radius Coded while creating a new video.

**Questions:**
Did the Codec disappears from OpenCV or did I miss one flag in the CMAKE configuration?

Of course I tried other config, but to me, I just had to activate WITH_FFMPEG and WITH_VFW flags. Do you have any tips on that?

Thanks !

Comment: is that the same machine / os-install ? on win, codecs don't come with opencv, you will have to install them seperately, some programs, like media players already do that under the hood, so it will be different from machine to machine.

Comment: Well yes to be fair Opencv 2.4.6 was not compiled on the same machine... I assumed it was no difference but apparently I was wrong. Thanks for your comment. I have difficulties to install CVID, so I installed XVID and it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution:

**I abandon CVID, and use the powerful XVID codec instead.**

1. Download Xvid installer from https://www.xvid.com/download/
2. Execute the file with admin's right
3. Use '-1' when creating a new video with opencv and select Xvid ( CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D') does not work)

Note:
An "xvid encoding status" window automatically opens when recording. To get rid of that simply:

1. Start / All Programs / Xvid / Configure encoded
2. Other options...
3. Deselect "Display encoding status"

Boum